# Separability of quotient in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I found a problem where it was requested to prove that if $X$ is separable Banach space and $Y$ a closed subspace of $X$, then the quotient $X/Y$ is also separable. What I cannot see clearly is wether the condition of $X$ being Banach is necessary or not. I sketched a proof of the problem and I did not use this condition at all. If anyone could guide me it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It is not needed and your proof is fairly short, isn't it? Oh but you forgot the hypothesis that $X$ is separable.

Comment: If $\{x_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is dense in $X$ and $q : X \to Z$ is surjective, then $\{q(x_n)\}_{n\ge 1}$ is dense in $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate what was stated in the comments, you can show more generally that if $X$ is a separable normed vector space and $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, then $X/Y$ is a separable normed vector space. So the hypothesis that $X$ is complete is not required to deduce that $X/Y$ is separable.